# Camel webSocket erro Buffer Size

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, apache-camel

I have a error with a camel route using the websockets. I send a rather heavy message and I get the following error:

> WARN  Frame discarded. Binary aggregation disabed for SCEP####{l(/########)<->r(/#########),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{WebSocketServletConnection######## p=WebSocketParser########## state=DATA buffer= g=WebSocketGenerator######### closed=false buffer=-1}

Would you have an idea to work around this problem?

Comment: Hilighted the error message.

Comment: Can you share your route code?